# ColdFusion 9.0.1 Hotfixes

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, hotfix

I have ColdFusion 9.0.1

Will installing ColdFusion 9 Hotfix 4 install Hotfixes 1, 2 & 3 together with it or do I have to install each Hotfix separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ColdFusion Hotfixes that you mentioned are cumulative. The key is in the name.  Notice that the Hotfixes you mentioned, 1 - 2 - 3 and 4, are named *Cumulative* Hotfix 1, *Cumulative* Hotfix 2, *Cumulative* Hotfix 3 and *Cumulative* Hotfix 4. Meaning that each of those Hotfix versions contain all of the changes from the previous Hotfix(es).  However, Adobe also releases some Hotfixes that are not cumulative.  See this Hotfix for ColdFusion 9 for example; [APSB13-03](https://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb13-03.html) (this Hotfix is included in Cumulative Hotfix 4 by the way). Notice that they name these updates "Security update: Hotfix available for ColdFusion". Unfortunately they use that term *Hotfix* again, but also notice that it does not say *Cumulative*.  It is a bit confusing and in my opinion this has always been a shortcoming for ColdFusion by Adobe.  Keeping the servers updated has been an artform in itself.  Finally Adobe has tried to remedy this with ColdFusion 10 and it's update process via the ColdFusion administrator.

In the end your best bet is to read the descriptions on the Hotfix pages themselves.  They will always report what previous fixes they include if any.  You can see what is included with Cumulative Hotfix 4 on the page found here: [ColdFusion Help / 
Cumulative Hotfix 4 | ColdFusion 9.0.1](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hotfix-4-coldfusion-901.html)

Comment: You should clarify that the ColdFusion CUMULATIVE Hotfixes are cumulative, there are still individual hotfixes that are released that are not. The instructions when applying the hotfixes (Cumulative or not) will tell you what `updates/*.jar` files to keep. When it's a cumulative hotfix, none will be kept.

Comment: Thanks guys. Read through the descriptions and turns out that the Cumulative Hotfix 4 does not contain the previous updates.

Comment: @raulprakash - You need to clarify which update you are referring to that is not included. Cumulative Hotfix 4 contains everything from Cumulative Hotfixes 3, 2 and 1 but also includes more fixes. From the page I linked in my answer: _Cumulative Hotfix 4 **consists of previously released Cumulative Hotfixes** and Security Hotfixes mentioned in the bulletins APSB11-29, APSB12-06, APSB12-15, APSB12-21, APSB12-26, and APSB13-03 along with few fixes were not part of Cumulative Hotfix 3._ _Cumulative Hotfix 4 also addresses issues (3511975, 3508592) reported with Cumulative Hotfix 3._